# Mobx reaction not tracking observable value passed from constructor parameter

Tags: mobx

I have this class:

```
class Mother{
   @observable
   name: string
   child: Child = new Child(this)
   constructor(){
       makeObservable(this)
   }
}

class Child{
    constructor(mother: Mother){
       const disposer = reaction(() => [mother.name], ()=>{})
       console.log(getDependencyTree(disposer));
    }
}
```

The output shows that the disposer has no dependency on mother.name. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the order of initialization: Child object is initialized before makeObservable(this) is called, thus mother.name is not yet an observable when running in reaction. By moving the intialization of child object after calling makeObservable(this), I solved the problem.

Comment: You are missing `super` in the child constructor.

Comment: @Ivan V : The Child class isn't a subclass of Mother so I don't need a super there (I use composition). Sorry for the confusing names.